# how to pass a variable from javascript to php after submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a script add rows to the table with textfields
everytime i click add row:

```
<script language = "javascript">

var x = 0;

function addRow(){

    var tbody = document.getElementById(tabID).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var row = document.createElement("tr")
    var data1 = document.createElement("td")    
    var data2 = document.createElement("td") 

    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);
    element.setAttribute("id", "Name"+x);
    element.setAttribute("style","width:95px");

    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.setAttribute("type", type);
    element1.setAttribute("name", type);
    element1.setAttribute("id", "Address"+x);
    element1.setAttribute("style","width:95px");

    var foo = document.tbody;

    data1.appendChild(element)
    data2.appendChild(element1)

    row.appendChild(data1)
    row.appendChild(data2)
    tbody.appendChild(row)

    x++;
}
</script>
```

How can I pass to php the value of my variable x after submitting, so I can count how many loop should I do?

Comment: TRY `document.getElementByID('divID').innerHTML = x`

Comment: add it as a hidden form element on the submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an input hidden field inside your form and initialize it with the value of the counter . you can use javascript as follows

```
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
 input.setAttribute("name", "counter");
 input.setAttribute("value", x);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `<input type="hidden" name="count_rows" value="0">` to your form, update its value to the row count when the form is submitted.

Comment: how can i get the value of it in php?

Comment: You can use `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` variable to get value of element.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Vinay already. Make use of name and value attributes of input elements. You can try out following code snippet.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    print_r($_POST);
    $counter= $_POST['counter'];   
    print_r("counter value : <b>". $counter. "</b>");

}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="5"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```